# Show $\int_0^a f(x)\,dx + \int_0^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx \ge ab$ for strictly increasing function $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inverse

Let $f: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ be continuous and strictly increasing and with $f(0) = 0$. Prove that $$\int_0^a f(x)\,dx + \int_0^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx \ge ab$$ for any $a, b > 0$, and give a condition for equality to hold.

Comment: Wiki has a nice proof without words of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#/media/File:Young.png

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132153/proof-of-youngs-inequality?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We remark that the integrals are well-defined by Theorem 6.9 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

> **Theorem 6.9 (Rudin).** *If $f$ is monotonic on $[a, b]$, and if $\alpha$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then $f \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$. (We still assume, of course, that $\alpha$ is monotonic.)*

By definition, there exists a sequence of partitions $(P_n)$ of $[0, a]$ such that$$U(P_n, f) \to \int_0^a f(x)\,dx$$and sequence of partitions $(Q_n)$ of $[0, b]$ such that$$L(Q_n, f^{-1}) \to \int_0^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx.$$Let $P_n' = P_n \cap f^{-1}(Q_n)$, $\tilde{P}_n = P_n' \cap [0, a]$, $Q_n' = Q_n \cap f(P_n)$, and $\tilde{Q}_n = Q_n' \cap [0, b]$. Then $U(\tilde{P}_n, f) \le U(P_n, f)$, $L(\tilde{Q}_n, f^{-1}) \ge L(Q_n, f^{-1})$ and so we have$$U(\tilde{P}_n, f) \to \int_0^a f(x)\,dx,\text{ }L(\tilde{Q}_n, f^{-1}) \to \int_0^b f^{-1}(x)\,dx.$$Replace $P_n$ by $\tilde{P}_n$ and $Q_n$ with $\tilde{Q}_n$. Because $f$ is strictly increasing,$$U(P_n, f) = \sum_{i=1}^p f(x_i)(x_i - x_{i-1}),$$where $P_n = \{x_0, \dots, x_p\}$, and similarly,$$L(Q_n, f^{-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^q f^{-1}(y_{j-1})(y_j - y_{j-1}),$$where $Q_n = \{y_0, \dots, y_q\}$. Also,$$ab = \left(\sum_{i=1}^p (x_i - x_{i-1})\right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^q(y_j - y_{j-1})\right).$$Let $P_n' = \{x_0, \dots, x_p, \dots, x_{p'}\}$ and $Q_n' = \{y_0, \dots, y_q, \dots, y_{q'}\}$. Realizing that, we can write$$U(P_n, f) = \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{y_j \le f(x_i)} (y_j - y_{j-1})(x_i - x_{i-1}) = \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{y_j \le f(x_i)} (x_i - x_{i-1})(y_j - y_{j-1})$$and$$L(Q_n, f^{-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^q \sum_{x_i \le f^{-1}(y_{j-1})}(x_i - x_{i-1})(y_j - y_{j-1}) = \sum_{j=1}^q \sum_{f(x_i) < y_j} (x_i - x_{i-1})(y_j - y_{j-1}),$$we obtain $ab \le U(P_n, f) + L(Q_n, f^{-1})$ since the left-hand side involves summing over fewer terms. Taking limits gives the required identity.

When $f(a) = b$, we obtain equality because the sums are equal. To see the converse, we use an argument like the one in Exercise 6.2 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

> **Exercise 6.2 (Rudin).** *Suppose $f \ge 0$, $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = 0$. Then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. (See [here](http://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%206.pdf?sequence=6) for a solution.)*

If $f(a) > b$, find a neighborhood $N$ of which this is true; one of the sums in the above argument will consist of more terms and the extra contribution will not converge to zero as this contribution is giving $\int_N (f(x) - b)\,dx > 0$. Similarly, if $f(a) < b$.

Answer (score 9):

Note that 
$$\int_0^cf(x)\,dx+\int_0^{f(c)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx=cf(c)$$

You can think of this as the area of the rectangle with $(0,0)$ for one corner and $(c,f(c))$ for the opposite corner.

Without loss of generality, let $f(a)\le b$. Then
$$\int_0^af(x)\,dx+\int_0^bf^{-1}(x)\,dx=af(a)+\int_{f(a)}^bf^{-1}(x)\,dx$$

Now since $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, we have $f^{-1}(x)>a$ for $x>f(a)$. Hence
$$\int_{f(a)}^bf^{-1}(x)\,dx\ge a\left(b-f(a)\right)$$
with equality if and only if $b=f(a)$.

Putting this together, we get
$$\int_0^af(x)\,dx+\int_0^bf^{-1}(x)\,dx\ge af(a)+a(b-f(a))=ab$$
with equality if and only if $b=f(a)$.

Comment: Well done!  +1....

Comment: The question has $f$ continuous. Is continuity actually needed here?

Answer (score 1):

As @Peter Woolfitt provide the solution, Here is my view

Set $f(x)=y,x=\varphi(y)$

$\varphi(f(x))=x$

Set $\displaystyle F(t)=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^t\varphi(y)dy-at$

take the derivative of this with respect to $F(t)$

we have $F'(t)=\varphi(t)-a$

and by the conditions $\varphi(0)=0$, $\varphi(t)$ monotonic increasing.

Set $F'(t)=0$, we got $\varphi(t_0)=a$, and $t_0=\varphi^{-1}(a)=f(a)$

When $t \in (0,t_0)$, $F(t)$  monotonic decreasing, $t \in (t_0,+\infty)$, $F(t)$ monotonic increasing

$$
F(t_0)=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^{t_0}\varphi(y)dy-at_0\\
$$

$$
F(t_0)=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^{f(a)}\varphi(y)dy-af(a)\\
$$

change of variable
$$
F(t_0)=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^{a}\varphi(f(x))d(f(x))-af(a)\\
$$

$$
F(t_0)=\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^{a}xd(f(x))-af(a)\\
$$

$$
F(t_0)=\int_0^af(x)dx+xf(x)\Big|_0^a-\int_0^{a}f(x)d(x)-af(a)=0\\
$$

Finally, we got $F(t)\geqslant 0$  when $t_0=f(a)=b$, $a=\varphi(b)$, the equation is satisfied

$$
\int_0^af(x)dx+\int_0^b\varphi(y)dy=ab
$$