# Does $\int^a_0 f+ \int^b_0 f^{−1} ≥ ab$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function, $f(0) =0$, 
$a>0$ and $b>0$, then $\int^a_0 f+ \int^b_0 f^{−1} ≥ ab$.

I honestly have no idea how to even begin a formal proof using Riemann integrability. Geometrically, it makes sense to me, but I do not know how to go from there. If anyone could share any hints or help, that'd be great.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132153/proof-of-youngs-inequality

Comment: "Geometrically, it makes sense to me" How, exactly? Please, tell us more.

Comment: Substitute $u=f^{-1}$ in the second integral. What happens if $a=f(b)$? What does this tell you about the general case?

Comment: @Arthur As in, when you think of integration as calculating area. The area of the rectangle with base $a$ and length $b$ is less than the added area calculated in the 2 integrals (due to the intervals we are integrating over with $f$ and $f^{-1}$).

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: consider $b=f(a)$.

Comment: Do we need continuity for this to be true?